# C - Next 10 prime numbers

Tags: c

I'm having some problems with a program I'm writing here.
It's supposed to print the next 10 prime numbers of given a value -- of course, it's not working. My logic is at fault here.

For example, if the program reads the number:

```
2
```

it's supposed to print:

```
3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31
```

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int n, i, count, primenumber = 1; // primenumber is a flag
    printf("Insert a number:\n");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    for (count = 0, n++; count < 10; n++, count++ ) {
        for (i = 2; i < n; i++) {
            if (n % i == 0) {
                primenumber = 0;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (primenumber)
            printf("%d\n", n);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I'd be very grateful if someone were to solve this problem.

Thanks.

**==UPDATE==**

I did it!

The crucial change was with the `primenumber` flag. I inserted it inside the `while`, always set to `1`. If set outside the `while`, the flag never resets and further tests won't occur -- depending on the number you give when prompted.

Here's the updated, functional code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int n, i, count = 0, primenumber; 
    printf("Insert a number: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    n++; // we do not want to print the prompted number
    while (count < 10) {
        primenumber = 1; // primenumber is set as flag
        for (i = 2; i < n / 2; i++) {
            if (n % i == 0) {
                primenumber = 0;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (primenumber) {
            printf("%d\n", n);
            count++; // increment count only when prime
        }
    n++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I decided not to delete this post. I'm sure someone, someday, will find it useful.

Comment: Rather than edit your question with the solution, revert this back to its unanswered state and post your own answer.  You can even accept it or another fine answer.

Answer (score 4):

Split your code a little arrange a bit more and present it

```
int isPrime ( int n )
{
    if (n <= 1) return 0; // zero and one are not prime
    unsigned int i;
    for (i=2; i*i<=n; i++) {
        if (n % i == 0) return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}

int main() {
    int n, count; // primenumber is a flag
    printf("Insert a number:\n");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    count = 0 ;
    n++ ;
    for ( ; count < 10; n++  ) {

        if (isPrime(n)) { // if its Prime, print and increase count
            printf("%d\n", n);
            count ++;
        }
        // Check next number until we get all our numbers
    }

    return 0; // All Done

}
```

Comment: Hail the abstraction approach!

Comment: Splitting the code is also a pretty good (and perhaps more organized) idea in this case. Still, I decided on a simpler approach. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

This is your modified working code.
In each step you should re initializing `primenumber=1` otherwise it gives only one number. Also `count` should be increases when you find a prime otherwise not.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int n, i, count, primenumber = 1; // primenumber is a flag
    printf("Insert a number:\n");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    for (count = 0, n++; count < 10; n++ ) {
        primenumber = 1;
        for (i = 2; i < n; i++) {
            if (n % i == 0) {
                primenumber = 0;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (primenumber){
            count++;
            printf("%d\n", n);
        }

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Oh! Thanks. I didn't refresh the page so I didn't see your answer. I've already solved the problem. Still, thanks for the attention -- we ended up with similar solutions!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution which will reduce the processing time, generally used for larger values of n:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int main() {
int n, i, count= 1, primenumber = 1, root; // primenumber is a flag
printf("Insert a number:\n");
scanf("%d", &n);
n++;
while(count!=11)
{
 root= sqrt(n);//You only need to check for range 2 to square root of number. This is the key ingredient of the code to reduce time complexity 
 primenumber = 1;
 for(i=2; i<= root; i++)
    {
    if(n%i==0)//As soon as it finds a number which perfectly divides it, break from loop checking n's nature
        {
        primenumber = 0;
        break;
        }       
    }
    if(primenumber==1)
        {
        printf("%d \t", n);
        count++;
        }
    n++;                
}
}
```

Comment: If you want to improve even more, you should only check if n is dividable by odd numbers.

Comment: I think that would actually increase the complexity since we'd be checking for every i `if(i%2!=0)`. So if i is an odd number, it'd go through this additional step.

Comment: Certainly @Valinho means `for(i=3; i<= root; i += 2)` and handle the even test separately.  Yet I disagree with that [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32664691/c-next-10-prime-numbers#comment53179212_32665177) as it is only a minor improvement.  This approach wisely goes to the square root of `n` than `n` - a _huge_ improvement +1.  Unfortunately,  it does so using `double` math.  Such math may lack the precision of `int` and fail with large numbers.  Consider an `isqrt()` function.

Comment: Thanks for clearing it out. You're right the complexity would only slightly improve. I don't understand the last part regarding double math. Could you link me to any reference to it as well as isqrt()?

Comment: I think you meant to say that sqrt() returns a double value. If that's what you meant, then I solved it already by assigning the value to `int root`.

Comment: @chux thanks for clearing that out. However, depending on the numbers size the performance improvement is noteable.

Comment: @Valinho Checking for odds only would at _best_,  double the performance.  That is a minor improvement.  This answer's improvement is `sqrt(n)` faster than OP's.  With a large prime `n` about 1,000,000,000, that is 30,000 times faster.  Consider [order of complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) versus small linear gains.

Comment: `sqrt(n)` is itself the problem when it converts the integer to a `double`.  Consider if `int` was 64-bit or code was using `long, long long`, etc.  Then the conversion to `double` could lose precision and generate a `sqrt()` near the mathematical desire one, but off by a few counts.  Example [isqrt()](http://www.cc.utah.edu/~nahaj/factoring/isqrt.c.html).  Another approach: compare `n/i >= i` for the terminating condition

Comment: @chux yea you are right. I know that `sqrt(n)` is a much better improvement. But why don't add every improvement you can think of? :p Also we should consider an another approach if we are talking about performance. The Sieve of Eratosthenes would be the best bet with prime numbers. ;)

Comment: @Valinho  "why don't add every improvement you can think of?"  Time/effort/money spent on minor improvements can be better applied to major improvements.

Comment: @chux It depends. I would surely bet that for scientifc purposes every minor improvement would be a good progress.

Comment: From what I can infer, both of you directly or indirectly believe in improving where it's necessary or where the improvement wouldn't cost much.

Comment: @Valinho following your suggestion, it will have to be noted that the input can not be less than 5 in general and not less than 4 for this problem.